# Android direct link to default browser

Tags: android

I have a webview with a website loaded in it. When I click on a link say "Full Site", I want to launch the default browser of the phone, how do I achieve this? Currently it loads the full site in the web view as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView` object:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
........

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.mysite.com")) {
           //Load the site into the default browser
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             startActivity(intent);
             return true;
        }
        // Load url into the webview
       return false;
    }
}
```

Just adjust the `if-statement` for your needed

Answer (score 1):

Refer [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Basically, you will have to

1. Create your own `webview` client
2. Override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. Place your logic of when to open links in browser and when not.
3. Set your custom webview client as your default `webview` client.

   `WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`